# How to get list of all languages that application supports

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to get list of all languages that application supports (apps from google play market)?
I need to do this task for many applications, so it will be preferable to get the quickest solution. However any ideas will be good at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

```
Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        ArrayList<String> localcountries=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Locale l:locales)
        {
            localcountries.add(l.getDisplayLanguage().toString());
        }
```

This might work for you.

Comment: I don't have access to the code :) I need to get supported languages not only for my app, but also for other applications from market.